# Asterisk Parallel Calling Find Answered Number

Tags: parallel-processing, asterisk, phone-call, ivr, pbx

I am trying asterisk parallel calling by doing.

```
same => n,dial(DAHDI/g0/09*********&DAHDI/g0/09*********,20,mM(ANSWERED))
```

But the problem is that how can know which number picks the call because the call is forwarding to macro and `${EXTEN}`, `${CDR(dst)}` variables dint gave me the desired result.

So how to get answered person's number in parallel calling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check dstchannel cdr variable.

Also very likly you have other variables, for example CHANNEL set to channel called, you can see all by do DumpChan call in y our macro,it will show you all variables.

As other option you can do calling via Local channel(via dialplan), in which you run ANSWERED macro.

Comment: as I mentioned in question Ive tried `${CDR(dst)}` but it dint gave me any value. Can you tell me any other variable?

Comment: In macro CHANNEL variable will be correctly set(i already say that). http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Detailed+Variable+List

Comment: Thanks, after `DumpChan()` I dint get any straightforward variable for dialled number but I got a variable `DIALLEDPEERNUMBER` variable which gave me the answerer number with group. I have to manualy split it to get the answered number.